# Номера строк кода в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Кто-нибудь работает в Android Studio? У меня в Logcat вышла ошибка с номером строки во всем коде. Не могу найти эту строчку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы перейти к строке с ошибкой, которую выдал *LogCat*, нужно кликнуть на подчеркнутом тексте с именем класса и номером строки, в окне редактора курсор установится на эту строку.
При этом, если ссылка на строку в *LogCat* серого цвета, то класс относится к Android API, а не к вашему приложению, соответственно вносить в него изменения нет никакого смысла. Ссылки на строки с ошибками в вашем приложении синего цвета (для темы Darcula).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, вы можете включить отображение номеров строк в окне редактора:

`Settings -> Editor -> Appearance: установить галку "Show line numbers"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 08-08 19:31:58.116      462-462/? E/Parcel﹕ Reading a NULL string not supported here. у меня выходит так и все красным